# Chrome randomly opens a tab and closes is is it malware?

Tags: google-chrome, malware

From time to time a tab opens really quickly and closes immediately. Is this some kind of malware or is it a known bug?

How could I find out?

Comment: When does it happen? When you are doing particular tasks? What are your habits? Specific sites etc?

Comment: it doesn't seem to follow any recognizable pattern. I dont visit any shady sites, at least none that im aware of.

Comment: So if you were to just sit on Google.com, no searches it would happen?

Comment: My gut says it is caused by a buggy extension. Try turning off some of those and see if you can identify the culprit.

Comment: thx ill try deinstalling the extensions. @AthomSfere it only happens like once or twice a day so I cant exactly say when it happens and when it doesnt.